# Is there anyway to know if thread has released CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have accidentally found a peculiar behaviour for which I am not getting any reason. In the program below there are 2 sections. First section is commented which creates 2 threads and does some work, in second section I added some code for getting primes which I tried for checking AsParallel Performance. AsParallel really decreased the time for program. But the thing which struck me most was when I commented the above section I got a improvement in time.
So my question is did the first section ,which I have commented, had kept the CPU busy enough. Or was there any other reason.

Please see time elapsed for 
1) When first section is not commented : Elapsed: 4260619 (Ticks)
2) When first section is commented :     Elapsed: 2700445 (Ticks)

```
class Program
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static int thStaticInt = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //new Thread(() =>
        //{
        //    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //    {
        //        thStaticInt++;
        //        Console.WriteLine("from first {0}", thStaticInt);

        //    }
        //}

        //).Start();


        //new Thread(() =>
        //{

        //    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //    {
        //        thStaticInt++;
        //        Console.WriteLine("from second {0}", thStaticInt);

        //    }


        //}

        //).Start();


        //Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        //Console.ReadLine();
       //Another section starts here

        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(3, 1000000);
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var primes = from n in numbers.AsParallel()
                     where Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n)).All(i => n % i != 0)
                     select n;

        IEnumerable<int> primeNumbers = primes.ToArray();

        watch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;             

        Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed {0}", ts.Ticks);           

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the two sections correlate to each other. This question is not presented very well.

Comment: Yes, sections are not correlated, I was just adding some code from here and there on threading and checking how the code works, but the fact is when above 2 threads are done with their tasks then how come they affect time elapsed.

Comment: Oh I see, you are saying if you include those then extra time is taken. I would assume because threads are not free. It takes time to allocate the thread from pool, assign the worker function, and then start the thread - at which point the OS takes over and allocates the thread to a CPU. There are various background activities going on, such as waiting for time-slices and potential context switches going on. These details are abstracted from your view of the thread's world.

Comment: Yes Adam, thanks for prompt reply. You have got my question, but I am still not understanding, when I can see that the 2 threads of first section when are done with their printing task on console. Should not I assume that since task is over hence they would free CPU.

Comment: Not sure. It could be that those threads have yet to be GC'd or returned to the pool, so when your parallel extensions code runs, it tries to grab many threads from the pool and starves it (or grabs less because 2 are unavailable). Can't really tell without digging deeper using some diagnostic tools.

Comment: I tried running the programs with Threads and without and I was not able to reproduce your issue. The average times are quite the same (little faster the one without threads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not grabbing the complete picture. Your profiling leads you to misinterpretation.

When you start a thread you request the operating system to start a thread, that doesn't mean it starts immediately, it's just a request. The OS decides when it runs your thread and for how long. That being said, in your example, your threads in the commented section could be run before, during or even after your second section.

The work in your threads is also a bit dubious. A counter to ten is very minimalistic. Also keep in mind that what you do, writing to the console, from a thread is only possible because the Console class does the thread synchronization for you. So, how does this fit in the timing? I have no idea.

Then there might be other processes with other threads running that you don't know of.

And on top of all of that you probably have a multicore processor, which might or might not affect everything.

Profiling is not an easy task. You should at least repeat your tests multiple times, corelate the results and have a solid understanding of everything involved.

Comment: There are few things which I am getting it as answer from your answer is that  
OS decides when it runs thread, but when I can see their printing task is done, I assume thread is done with task. 

for counter being 10 only I have purposefully set it low to let the thread end. 

I am getting the fact that there might be some other processes which may be consuming CPUs.

Comment: Accepted this with comments from Adam, Thanks Jef and Adam